# Send customized text from one JTextpane to another JTexpane

Tags: java, swing, chat, jtextfield, jtextarea

I am developing  one simple Java based application in Swing. I have one text pane where I customize it's text using text editor like making text bold, italic, inserting smiley. Now in my application this customize text goes forward to another text pane, but when I send it to another text pane it shows simple text instead of customize text.

I need to know how do i forward customize text from text pane to another text pane.

I am basically using this concept for my chat application. Hope this gives you all clear idea about my work.

Comment: BTW - don't destroy my edits!  Use the little 'edit' link below the question to edit a post, rather than the 'back' button.  But you might as well leave Swing in there now.

Comment: @AndrewThompson i am using edit link only

Answer (score 1):

> Should I use text pane or editor pane instead of text area?

Simple answer to a simple question.  Yes.

`JTextArea` is intended for plain text.  For styled text, use a `JEditorPane` or `JTextPane`.  See [How to Use Editor Panes and Text Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html) for more details, and pretty (styled) images like this:

[image: Text Sampler Demo]

Answer (score 0):

1. whatever setting is selected, just note the state - the font, bold, italic, etc
2. pass the state to the text area
3. Before displaying in to the text area, apply the same state to it